# why the function io.write() does not work in lua

Tags: lua, io

I want to count the number of occurrences of words in a text and give the top ten words and their number of occurrences.

I use the function io.open() to open a input file as file-handle, then do something on the file-handle, put the results in a table. then close the input file-handle. and open a output file which is a new file as file-handle try to write the results to this file. but it does not work. the code is following.

the txt "ioinput.txt" is input file which has a article and the txt "iooutput.txt" is the output file

```
input_file = io.open("ioinput.txt", r)

--[[
This block of code is to count the number of word,
which has been verified by the print function in the following.
--]]

input_file:close()

output_file = io.open("iooutput.txt", a)

local n = 10
for i = 1, n do
    output_file:write(words[i], "\t", counter[words[i]], "\n")
    --print(words[i], "\t", counter[words[i]], "\n")
end
output_file:flush()
output_file:close()
```

Comment: I assume the print you have commented showed that the loop was being executed and the data was what you expected? also when you say "does not work" what does that mean? is the file blank? or maybe full of gibberish? do you get an error?

Comment: I just noticed `io.open("iooutput.txt", a)` you have `a` not `"a"` this means your second arg is `nil` and the defualt is to `"r"` so you are in read mode, that is why write is not working. same thing is "wrong" with `io.open("ioinput.txt", r)` but it "works" here because teh default mode is read .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the [Lua 5.4 Reference Manual: io.open](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-io.open)

> **io.open (filename [, mode])**
>
> This function opens a file, in the mode specified in the string mode.
> In case of success, it returns a new file handle.
>
> The mode string can be any of the following:
>
> ```
> "r": read mode (the default);
> "w": write mode;
> "a": append mode;
> "r+": update mode, all previous data is preserved;
> "w+": update mode, all previous data is erased;
> "a+": append update mode, previous data is preserved, writing is only allowed at the end of file.
> ```
>
> The mode string can also have a 'b' at the end, which is needed in
> some systems to open the file in binary mode.

Please note that the optional mode is to be provided as a string.

In your code

`input_file = io.open("ioinput.txt", r)`  and `output_file = io.open("ioinput.txt", a)`

your using modes `r` and `a`. Both nil values. The mode defaults to `"r"` which is read mode. You cannot write to a file opened in read mode.